# Using fopen() in another function

Tags: c, fopen

I'm trying to work with files in C. I wanted to have a function that receives a pointer to FILE, asks the name of the file to read, and initalize it for reading. So, I wrote it like this:

```
void initFileReading(FILE* fp){
    char dic[40];
    printf("Dictionary file: ");
    scanf("%40[^\n]", dic);

    fp = fopen(dic, "r");
}

int main(){
    int diff, i, nWords, Len;
    char str[16];
    FILE* fp;

    initFileReading(fp);

    fscanf(fp, "%s", str);
    printf("%s", str);

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to run it I get a SegFault. However if I put what's in the function in main it runs fine. Can anyone give me a little insight in this?

Thank you.

Comment: Note that while using `"%40[^\n]"` is (mostly) a good idea, you have to specify the length without the terminating null in the format strinmg, so either use `"%39[^\n]"` or `char str[41];` to avoid 1-byte over-writes.  (Yes, it is not consistent with modern idioms, but changing it would have broken a lot of code, so it wasn't changed.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you seem like an experienced C programmer, why not just suggest the proper solution (`fgets()`) instead?

Comment: @user3477950: Two reasons (of debatable merit).  (1) The question uses `scanf()` which is not automatically wrong, and pointing out the subtleties of using `scanf()` correctly is an important part of helping on SO, and (2) using `fgets()` is not a trivial replacement as you have to be prepared to deal with the newline character in the input string, and be prepared to deal with its absence (indicating that the input string -- filename -- was longer than the space allowed for it).  _[...and then there's "why didn't I think of that?"...]_

Answer (score 2):

Assigning to `fp` will not modify the variable in the calling function - you only have a pointer to a FILE, not a pointer to a pointer to a FILE. But to modify the pointer in the calling function you need exactly this:

```
void initFileReading(FILE** fpp){
    char dic[40];
    printf("Dictionary file: ");
    scanf("%39[^\n]", dic);

    *fpp = fopen(dic, "r");
}

int main(){
    int diff, i, nWords, Len;
    char str[16];
    FILE* fp;

    initFileReading(&fp);

    fscanf(fp, "%s", str);
    printf("%s", str);

    return 0;
}
```

However, it would be cleaner to simply `return` the newly opened file:

```
FILE* initFileReading(){
    char dic[40];
    printf("Dictionary file: ");
    scanf("%39[^\n]", dic);

    return fopen(dic, "r");
}
```

In your main function you can then simply use `fp = initFileReading();`

Answer (score 0):

The values passed as arguments to a function are copied to local variables inside the function. So, 'fp' in 'initFileReading' is a local variable, and when you assign the return value of fopen to it you aren't assigning that value to 'fp' in 'main'. If you want to do that, 'initFileReading' must accept a pointer (a memory address) to FILE*. In that case, the memory address value is copied also, but when you modify the memory that it points to, you are modifying 'fp' in main.

The function will be like this:

```
void initFileReading(FILE** fp){
    char dic[40];
    printf("Dictionary file: ");
    scanf("%40[^\n]", dic);

     *fp = fopen(dic, "r");
}
```

and you call it

```
initFileReading(&fp);
```

where & is the address operator, that returns the address of that variable.